# Pass Success variable to code

Tags: jquery

How can I pass a variable that has been calculated in the success callback of an ajax function, to the document.ready ?

I have this code

```
 function loadActions()
        {
            var countDiv;


            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                url:"modules/actions/actions.php",      

                success : function (data) {



                    $("#actions-container").html(data);
                    $('.action-details').hide();
                    countDiv = $('.action-tab-odd').length + $('.action-tab-even').length ;



                }

            });

            return countDiv;
        }

   $(document).ready(function(){



        var count = loadActions();


   });
```

But count is allways undefined. How can I get this to work?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't - `$.ajax` is asynchronous.
That means your code after the call of `$.ajax` will be processed even if the call you're making take a long time.

Returning something is obviously completely not a thing that can be done.

You could however call a callbackfunction in the `success` once its done with your value so it'll be handled. Or use it directly in your `success` method. If you need your data directly, just don't use `$.ajax` and create the right code server side.

Comment: This is the most acceptable answer although it does solve my problem. I ended up solving it by another means. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

This is async call and execution of ready may finish before success method is invoked, so make a new function and pass values from success to that function

```
success : function (data) {

       $("#actions-container").html(data);
       $('.action-details').hide();
       countDiv = $('.action-tab-odd').length + $('.action-tab-even').length ;
       MyCounting(countDiv);

  }

function  MyCounting(count)
{

}
```

Comment: OK. And how can I consume that new function as I just want one value? Should I create the needed events inside that function?

Comment: You can call function as given in answer and you will have event which you have already binded.

Comment: Just fyi, i didn't do it... >.<

Comment: Here you go with a +1 for compensation;)

Answer (score 1):

This code is async, so you get a delayed result. In the meantime, the assignment `var count = ...` already has been done. You need a callbackfunction that sets the variable.

Try this:

```
var count;

loadActions(function(value){count = value});
```

and your loadActions function:

```
function loadActions(callback){
   ...

   success : function (data) {
      callback(countDiv);
```

See the **[example here](http://jsfiddle.net/poikl/dyVpz/)** (i replaced the call with a timeout but it's effectively the same)

If that does not fit your purpose, you still can switch the ajax request to be synchronous:

```
$.ajax({
    async = false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$.ajax` makes by default an asynchronous call to the requested url, which means that the `return countDiv;` line will be *probably* reached before the success callback function get called.

One solution is to make that url call synchronous by adding the `async = false` option:

```
$.ajax({
    // ...
    async = false,
    // ...
});
```

If that suits you, do not forget that the url call isn't asynchronous anymore...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function loadActions()
    {
        var countDiv;
```

//You want to to think about what you are returning
//Below, you are returning the ajax object as the function results.  In your example, you are returning a variable out of scope in a function that doesn't return a value (your success function doesn't return a value) - > see  below.

```
      return $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            url:"modules/actions/actions.php",      

            success : function (data) {
                $("#actions-container").html(data);
                $('.action-details').hide();
                return $('.action-tab-odd').length + $('.action-tab-even').length ;
            },
            error: function (){
                return false;
            }

        });
    }
```

//If you do not want to check for errors in the ajax call, you can omit the error call, and right before the return in the success statement, you can include a conditional that checks if the $('.action-tab-odd') value is set properly -something like:

```
if(typeof $('.action-tab-odd').length !== "undefined" || $('.action-tab-odd').length !== 0)
  {
     return false;
  } 
return $('.action-tab-odd').length + $('.action-tab-even').length
```

//then on document.ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        if(loadActions()){
            var count=loadActions();
            console.log(count);
        }


         })
```

There are other ways to do this, utilizing $.Deferred (I have struggled with this issue a lot myself), but this way seems to be closest to what you are trying to accomplish.